# Firebase Cloud Functions: Error while deploying function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm deploying the following function to firebase:

```js
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const firebase = require("firebase-admin");
firebase.initializeApp()
var firestore = firebase.firestore()

exports.resetCreditsForFreeUsers = functions.pubsub
    .schedule('* * * * *')
    .onRun(async (context) => {
        const users = firestore.collection('tests')
        const user = await users.get()
        user.forEach(snapshot => {
            snapshot.ref.update({ balance: 10 })
        })
        return null;
    })
```

with the command `firebase deploy --only functions` and the output is:

```
i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> lint
> eslint

+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
+  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled

Error: Failed to make request to https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/*PROJECTNAME*/services/runtimeconfig.googleapis.com
```

I can't figure out how to solve this error.

**EDIT WITH Dharmaraj answer**
I tried your answer with Promise.

Error:

```
+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged C:\Users\andre\Documents\firebase-functions\functions (78.21 KB) for uploading

Error: Failed to make request to https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v2alpha/projects/betty-sport/locations/-/functions
```

**EDIT changing update() with set()**

```
Error: Failed to list functions for betty-sport
```

Comment: Can you try refactoring the code as in my answer? Also do retry deploying after all required APIs are enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.update()` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) so you should wait for it to resolve. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
exports.resetCreditsForFreeUsers = functions.pubsub
  .schedule('* * * * *')
  .onRun(async (context) => {
    const users = firestore.collection('tests')
    const user = await users.get()

    const promises = user.docs.map(d => d.ref.update({ balance: 10 }));

    await Promise.all(promises);

    return null;
  })
```

Alternatively, you can also use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) to update up to 500 documents at once instead of individually updating them.

Comment: Tried, and edited the question with new error

Comment: @faccio can you try `firebase logout` and `firebase login` again in the CLI?

Comment: It seems working. Each time I want to deploy I have to reauth, otherwise it is not working